# How to handle this situation

Tags: support, close-reasons, moderators, closed-questions, moderation

One of my [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124242/disabling-the-google-app) was recently closed by moderator Matthew Read.

From the comment he posted, it appears he felt my question constituted "polling".

In fact, I was not interested in "polling", but was simply open to answers from people using any version of Android.

I promptly edited the question by removing all text that could possibly be misconstrued as "polling".  I then posted a comment stating that I had edited the text, and asked Mr. Read to re-open the question.  That was almost a week ago, but nothing has changed.

Unless there is a valid reason for this question to remain closed, please re-open it.

Comment: For what it's worth: it currently has 2 re-open votes (one is mine), and I left a comment suggesting to Matthew a reconsideration of his binding vote. In a situation like that, IMHO a "flag for mod attention" might be justified; as you have the required rep, you could bring that up in chat before to get some "backing".

Comment: @Izzy  Thanks Izzy.  The other re-open vote is mine.  I took your advice, and performed a "flag for mod attention".  I didn't mention it in chat first, due to time constraints and having no experience with chat on this SE.

Comment: I'd suggest a title more descriptive here, like "Trying to reopen a question closed as off-topic by a moderator". I also think naming the mod is not really necessary. My 2¢...